# How can I fix 'openCV has no attribute VideoCapture' in python

Tags: python, opencv

I currently have opencv-python 4.5.3.56 installed and running in Python 3.8. However, whenever I try to use the library, I get the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ryck5/Documents/FA2021/ECEG301/camerademo/color_detection.py", line 108, in <module>
    dj.open_camera()
    cap = opencv.VideoCapture(0)
AttributeError: module 'opencv' has no attribute 'VideoCapture'
```

I also tried `print(opencv.__version__)`, but that gave me the same error, just with version instead of VideoCapture. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling opencv countless times, using the opencv-contrib-python library instead, but nothing has worked. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I consider this question to have arisen from a **typo**. you simply didn't use any documentation or other resources before typing your code.

Answer (score 0):

**opencv** library is used as `cv2` namespace in python environment. Most probably you have installed `python-opencv` and using it.

Try:

`import cv2` and then use `cv2.VideoCapture()`.

> Also, this is why `opencv.__version__` is giving you error as there is no `opencv` object or library here. Try `cv2.__version__`.